# integration by parts of double integral

Tags: calculus

I have a question for integration by parts. If we have $$\int\int_Uf(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)dxdy,$$ how can we integrate by parts?

I guess it might be $$\int_{\partial U}f(x,y)g(x,y)dS-\int\int_Ug(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dxdy,$$ but we only consider the variable $x$, not $y$.

I guess we can also view $$\int\int_Uf(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)dxdy=\int_a^b\int_{c(y)}^{d(y)}f(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)dxdy,$$ then we have $$\int_a^b\int_{c(y)}^{d(y)}f(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)dxdy=\int_b^af(x,y)g(x,y)\big|_{c(y)}^{d(y)}dy-\int_a^b\int_{c(y)}^{d(y)}g(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dxdy.$$

But it looks so weird. And what if we cannot write $y$ as an explicit function of $x$? I feel the first one is right. But just feel so. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: I does look weird. The most weird is the iterated integral where the *outer* limits depend on the *inner* integration variable as $c(x)$ and $d(x)$ do. Another thing: $\iint_{\partial U}$ should be a *one dimensional* integration since $\partial U$ is a boundary ($\approx$ a curve, one dimensional manifold), why *two* integrals here? At last, you may look at [some examples](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap12.pdf) how to deal with such a thing. (Hint: try $F=f\cdot g$.)

Comment: I have edited it. I guess this time it looks not that weird. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It is better now. The first and the third integral in the last equality are clearly $\iint_U$, the middle one is to be understood. Note that it is *not* your guess above as $\int_{\partial U}fg\,dS$, but close to it. Hint: $dy=n_x\,dS$ where $n=(n_x,n_y)$ is the *unit outward* normal to $\partial U$. (May look at [some more explanations](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap14.pdf).)

Comment: I think I understand your explanation. The middle one should be $\int_{\partial U}fgn_xdS$. Thank you very much!